# How to fix the ObjectParameterError error in Mongoose interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pass String object to the function to create an entry in MongoDB. This interface is working fine when the data is coming from HTTP post, but it is not working if the data is coming from Websocket.

This code is not working, and throwing an ObjectParameterError error.

```
wss.on('connection', ws => {
   ws.on('message', message => {
   console.log(`Received message => ${message}`);
   console.log(typeof(message));
   console.log(message.constructor.name);  ==> prints String class
   Fnode.create(message, function (err, post) {
       if (err) console.log(`Received error => ${err}`);
       console.log(`Received post => ${post}`);
   });
 });
});
```

The error is:

```
Received message => 
 {"ptName":"java","agentId":"localhost.localdomain","tId":4442,"evType":"thread start","desc":"tomcat process","ptId":1,"evId":"clone","tStamp":"2019-01-13T05:47:48.253639314Z","tName":"java"}
    string
    String
    Received error => ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got 
 {"ptName":"java","agentId":"localhost.localdomain","tId":4442,"evType":"thread start","desc":"tomcat process","ptId":1,"evId":"clone","tStamp":"2019-01-13T05:47:48.253639314Z","tName":"java"}
```

This code is working fine.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(`Received message => ${req.body}`);
console.log(typeof(req.body));
console.log(req.body.constructor.name);  ==> prints Object class
   Fnode.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
   if (err) return next(err);
   res.json(post);
 });
});
```

Comment: what is the typeof(message) in web socket code?

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets support sending and receiving: strings, typed arrays (ArrayBuffer) and Blobs. Javascript objects must be serialized to one of the above types before sending. 
for sending your object use this :

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(object));
```

or

```
ws.send(BSON.serialize(object));
```

When you receive a Web Socket message you will need to deserialize it. and convert it to JSON

```
    wss.on('connection', ws => {
       ws.on('message', message => {
       message = JSON.parse(message);
       console.log(`Received message => ${message}`);
       console.log(typeof(message));
       console.log(message.constructor.name);  ==> prints String class
       Fnode.create(message, function (err, post) {
           if (err) console.log(`Received error => ${err}`);
           console.log(`Received post => ${post}`);
       });
     });
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you approve of my answer so that other people can use it. @user10948445